# FlowRouter on Account.onLogin() doesn't redirect properly in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

All my routes are working fine and my routes are declared in "**D:\test\imports\startup\client\routes.js**".

1. I added a package "gwendall:auth-client-callbacks".
2. I added below piece of code at the end of all routes.

   ```
    Accounts.onLogin(function(){
      console.log(Meteor.user().profile.customerType == 'CLIENT'); // shows true
      if(Meteor.user().profile.customerType == 'CLIENT'){
         FlowRouter.go('client');
      } else {
         console.log('else');
      }
   });

   Accounts.onLogout(function(){
     FlowRouter.go('/');
   });
   ```

While the logout module runs perfect, the onLogin() call redirects to page but with "*FlowRouter.notFound*" action.

So below is the page returned when I login successfully.

[image]

**How can I manage to redirect to correct path instead of *'notFound*' path ?**

**-------------UPDATED-------------**

***PROJECT\imports\startup\client\routes.js***

```
var clientRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
  prefix: '/client',
  name: 'client',
  triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
    if(!Meteor.userId()){FlowRouter.go('/');}

    console.log('/Client route called.');
  }]
});

clientRoutes.route('/', {
  name: 'client-dashboard',
  action: function() {
    console.log("Dashboard called.");
    BlazeLayout.render('App_AuthClient', { main : 'App_UserDashboard'});
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you need 3rd party package for `onLogin` event? It exists by default. See [`AccountsCommon#onLogin(func)`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **UPDATE**

After question was updated it appeared that `client` was the name of the FlowRouter group instead of route name, which is `client-dashboard` and should be used to redirect user.

---

Since you are using FlowRouter I would suggest following approach:

1. Create two routes groups:

   ```
   const protectedRoutesGroup = FlowRouter.group({
       triggersEnter: [function () {
           if (!Meteor.userId) {
               FlowRouter.go('login')
           }
       }]
   });

   const guestOnlyRoutesGroup = FlowRouter.group({
       triggersEnter: [function () {
           if (Meteor.userId) {
               FlowRouter.go('homepage')
           }
       }]
   });
   ```
2. Then you define your routes respectively:

   ```
   protectedRoutesGroup.route('/', {
       name: 'homepage',
       action () {
           BlazeLayout.render(baseLayout, { main: 'template_name' });
       }
   });

   guestOnlyRoutesGroup.route('/', {
       name: 'login',
       action () {
           BlazeLayout.render(baseLayout, { main: 'login_template' });
       }
   });
   ```

Thus, FlowRouter will handle redirection based on Meteor.userId cookie value.

And the reason you got redirected to 404, I would guess that there is no route with name "client" defined.

Comment: there is route with name "client".....I get there when i refresh page? why is this happening?

Comment: @AnkurSoni can you provide your route declaration at least? + You can use `FlowRouter._routes` before the redirect to see if your route actually exists when FlowRouter tries to redirect to it.

Comment: Updated above. kindly refer question and Yes! the path exists when I output the `FlowRouter._routes` on console.

Comment: @AnkurSoni now that you've updated your code I see that there is no route named "client". You have routes group named "client". You need to use "client-dashboard" name.

Comment: @ Artūrs : Thanks a lot, that was the perfect answer. Could you please update the post as an answer. I shall accept the answer and close this topic.